# Responsive Layout in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, layout

Which is the best option to create a responsive layout design? The first question is what should be the height and width of every view (it should be in percentage, match constraint or wrap content using constraint layout).

- If we use wrap content I think there is no way to create a responsive design with help of wrap content because if content increase the view will take all the space of the screen either vertically or horizontally
- If we use match constraint then, in that case, it's good, but sometimes it is looking awesome on Android Studio but when we run it on a real device it doesn't look the same
- The last option is to use percentage, in that case, I think first we have to check our item list vertically and horizontally and provide them space according to their content priority and usage

So what will be the best case to create a responsive layout in XML for Android?

Answer (score 0):

1. It depends on UI.generaly people use the 2nd and 3rd methods because by using constraints and percentages you can get responsive UI.
2. sometimes it depends on your requirement.
3. if you are using the percentage method and you set the imageView at 10 % it's looking proper on your device but sometimes it happened that in a small device that imageView is not looked proper

**So the moral is all your three methods can be applied as per UI you can not make all designs responsive using 1 method**